# How to understand the recipirocal lattice vectors for BCC?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, crystals

I know that if a set of vectors R constitutes a Bravis Lattice then the reciprocal vector Q is a wave vector such that Q.R = 2nPi where n is an integer. In this definition, Q represents a set of wave vectors that give a plane wave with the periodicity of the Bravis lattice.
However when looking at the BCC unit cell we can see that an atom lies at R1 =(0.5,0.5,0.5) and the rest lie at R2 = (0,0,0) in fractional coordinates. What confuses me is that if Q.R2 = 2nPi then Q.R1 = nPi. Therefore, Q does not is not a set of wave vectors that represents the periodicity of the lattice vector (when considering the middle atom). I was wondering if someone could help me out with where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the definition $\vec{Q}_i \cdot \vec{R}_j = 2\pi \delta_{i,j}$ ($\delta_{i,j}$ being the Kronecker delta), you have to take the primitive lattice vectors, not the conventional ones. The primitive unit cell spanned by $\vec{R}_i$ only contains 1 atom. By construction you can, from any given lattice point, reach every other lattice point by translating by a linear combination of primitive lattice vectors, so $e^{i \vec{Q} \cdot \vec{r}}$ gives you exactly lattice periodic plane waves.